# Scala dropWhile predicate with iterators

Tags: scala, iterator, program-entry-point, read-eval-print-loop

I have question regarding the use of Scala's dropWhile predicate with an iterator.
Here I have a simple iterator creation:

```
scala> val it = Iterator("a" , "number" , "of" , "words")
it: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator
```

Next I use a dropWhile predicate on it:

```
scala> it dropWhile ( _.length < 2 )
res52: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator
```

Next I perform a next command on the Iterator:

```
   scala> it next
   res53: String = of
```

Now notice the iterator next command returns "of" , one past what it should be.

If I put this same code in a main function, the next will return "a".
This is rather confusing. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/Iterator.html):

> It is of particular importance to note that, unless stated otherwise,
>   one should never use an iterator after calling a method on it. The two
>   most important exceptions are also the sole abstract methods: next and
>   hasNext.

You need to assign the result of `dropWhile` to a new variable and continue using that e.g.

```
val remaining  = it dropWhile ( _.length < 2 )
remaining.next
```

Answer (score 0):

[Scala docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_43.html) explains `Iterators` as

> `An iterator is not a collection, but rather a way to access the elements of a collection one by one. The two basic operations on an iterator it are next and hasNext. A call to it.next() will return the next element of the iterator and advance the state of the iterator. Calling next again on the same iterator will then yield the element one beyond the one returned previously. If there are no more elements to return, a call to next will throw a NoSuchElementException.`

## REPL

And when you applied `it dropWhile ( _.length < 2 )` in REPL, its assigned to  `res52`

> `scala> it dropWhile ( _.length < 2 )
>   res52: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator`

`"a" , "number"` are already accessed. So applying `it next` gave you `of` which is **100 % correct**

## Main

In `main()`, you must have done

```
val it = Iterator("a" , "number" , "of" , "words")
it dropWhile ( _.length < 2 )
print(it next)
```

You can clearly see that `it dropWhile ( _.length < 2 )` is not assigned as in REPL. Thus, **`"a" , "number"` are not yet accessed**

So `it next` printed `a` in `main()`

I hope the explanation is helpful